# Jquery - Unable to auto-select specific option derived from callback

Tags: php, jquery

Objective: Product Three is selected by default when page is loaded, using Jquery and not hard-coded.

1. Data from MySQL:

```
    PDID  PDNAME
    pd1   Product One
    pd2   Product Two
    pd3   Product Three
    pd4   Product Four
```

2. HTML

```
    <select id="product-selection">
    </select>
```

3. Jquery

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.post('load.php', {
            req: 'load_product'
        }, function(data, status) {
            $("#product-selection").empty().append(data);
        });
        // $('#product-selection').val("pd3"); <-Refer to Item 5. Problem
    });

    Callback Return:
    <option selected disabled></option>
    <option value="pd1">Product One</option>
    <option value="pd2">Product Two</option>
    <option value="pd3">Product Three</option>
    <option value="pd4">Product Four</option>
```

4. Everything is fine at this stage. Dropdown Selection is loaded with Callback Values.
5. Problem:
   Have tried the following in Jquery but pd3 is not selected when page is loaded.

```
    1. $('#product-selection').val("pd3");
    2. $('#product-selection').val("pd3").change();
    3. $('#product-selection').val("pd3").trigger('change');
    4. $('#product-selection option[value="pd3"]').prop('selected', true);
    5. $('#product-selection option[value="pd3"]').prop('selected', true).change();
    6. $('#product-selection option[value="pd3"]').prop('selected', true).trigger('change');

    Have tried prop / attr, ('selected', true) / ('selected', 'selected') as well. Not working.
```

Appreciate if any solution could be provided. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following two variants both work for me:

```
$('#product-selection option[value="pd3"]').prop("selected", true)
$('#product-selection option[value="pd3"]').prop("selected", "selected")
```

Make sure to run this code *after* the HTML from the server has been inserted:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $.post('load.php', {
        req: 'load_product'
    }, function(data, status) {
        $("#product-selection").empty().append(data);

        // Selection code needs to go into this callback,
        // which is executed after the response comes back.
        $('#product-selection option[value="pd3"]').prop("selected", "selected")

    });

    // Selection code SHOULD NOT be here, because this is executed
    // right after the POST request is made.
    // When code at this place is executed, the response has most
    // likely not come back yet.
});
```

Comment: Thanks. For my case, the Jquery Callback is loaded in one template, when user access to the HTML page, it call up the template first then select the respective product that is related to the user. Therefore I am not able to put the Selection Code into the callback template, i.e. after the function(data, status).

Answer (score 0):

please check it.
You can set the dynamic value 'pdvalue'. when page load time you can use it.

```js
var pdvalue = "pd2";

$(document).ready(function() {
        $.post('load.php', {
            req: 'load_product'
        }, function(data, status) {
            $("#product-selection").empty().append(data);
        });
        // $('#product-selection').val("pd3"); <-Refer to Item 5. Problem
    });
    
    
    (function setpd(){
    $('#product-selection option[value="'+ pdvalue +'"]').prop("selected", true)
    })(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="product-selection">
<option selected disabled></option>
    <option value="pd1">Product One</option>
    <option value="pd2">Product Two</option>
    <option value="pd3">Product Three</option>
    <option value="pd4">Product Four</option>
    </select>
```